# Problem with the autopostback in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have a table within an updatepanel and onload I'm creating dynamic dropdownlist with the autopostback equal to yes.

Even though the dropdownlist is inside the updatepanel, it still does a postback where the screen blinks.

Why does this occur?

```
tblcell = New TableHeaderCell
inputDrop = New DropDownList
inputDrop.ID = "pax_type" & CStr(iteration)

inputDrop.Items.Add(New ListItem("-", "-"))
inputDrop.Items.Add(New ListItem("M", "M"))
inputDrop.Items.Add(New ListItem("F", "F"))
inputDrop.Items.Add(New ListItem("C", "C"))
inputDrop.Items.Add(New ListItem("W", "W"))
inputDrop.AutoPostBack = True
tblcell.Controls.Add(inputDrop)
tblrow.Cells.Add(tblcell)
```

Here is the aspx, markup code below:

```
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:Table ID="passenger_table" runat="server" Width="100%"/>
       </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Where are you adding the DropDownList to the table and are you also recreating it on postbacks? Please post also the aspx markup of the UpdatePanel.